# Order a list of Names by last name

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a nested list with the following structure:

```
list={{{"Clastname", "firstname"}, "STRING1"},{{"Blastname", "firstname"}, "STRING2"},{{"Alastname", "firstname"}, "STRING3"};
```

How can I sort the list in alphabetical order for the lastname so that the output is

```
{{{"Alastname", "firstname"}, "STRING3"},{{"Blastname", "firstname"}, "STRING2"},{{"Clastname", "firstname"}, "STRING1"}
```

Comment: The canonical sort will go by the first element (I think), so `Sort[list]` does what you want.  To be more explicit, you could use `SortBy[Part[#, 1, 1] &] @ list`

Comment: @JasonB.: Thx works perfectly! Just did not came across ````Part````

Comment: `SortBy[First@*First]@list` `Composition` with operator form of `SortBy`.